# Passing values from one page to another in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

In below code, the value is not passed from one page to another.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<script type="text/javascript">

    function generateRow() {
        var myvar = "testuser";

        '<%Session["temp"] = "' + myvar +'"; %>';
        window.location = "WebForm2.aspx";
    }
</script>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div runat="server">
        <input id="Button1" type="button" onclick="generateRow()" value="button" />
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

What is the problem in above code?

Answer (score 8):

You cannot set a session with Javascript. Your output JS file will be exactly what you wrote down.

You can do it like this:

```
window.location = "WebForm2.aspx?temp=" + myvar;
```

And in Webform2 you can do:

```
Request.querystring["temp"];
```

Answer (score 5):

Global variables in one page are not kept by the next.

If you want this *client-side*, you have three options (at least):

1. Pass the variable to the next page on the query string, e.g.:

   ```
   window.location = "WebForm2.aspx?myvar=" + encodeURIComponent(myvar);
   ```
2. Use a cookie (millions of examples online, I won't repeat them, bit of a pain to read the cookie).
3. Use client-side session storage or local storage, both of which are covered [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/). Here's the client-side session storage example:

   ```
   // Setting
   sessionStorage.myvar = myvar;

   // Getting (on the next page)
   var myvar = sessionStorage.myvar;
   ```

   (`sessionStorage` is a global variable provided by the browser.)

   This works on [just about any browser you need to care about](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage) (IE8+, and modern versions of basically everything else).

Server-side, both option 1 and 2 would work, but 1 would make the most sense.

Comment: I had never thought of using sessionStorage. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @TJCrowder ... your the MAN !