# click an <a href using javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this JS and HTML Code:

```
<div id="EditPage" class="EditPagePopup">
    <div class="EditPagePopupWrapper">
    <iframe id="EditPageFrame" width="100%" height="75%" src=""></iframe>
    <div id="JQueryPopupRight"><a id="JQueryRefreshIframe">&#x21bb;</a> <a id="JQueryClose">&#215;</a></div>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a#MiniPopupWindow").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //On click, open the page (<a value> value) in the above iframe/popup window
        $("#EditPageFrame").attr("src", $(this).attr("value"));
        $("a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");

        JQueryPopup('#EditPage');
    });

    $("a#JQueryRefreshIframe").click(function (e) {
        document.getElementById('EditPageFrame').contentWindow.location.reload(true);
    });
});
```

then i have a href links like:

```
<a id="MiniPopupWindow" value="http://www.google.co.uk/">test</a>
```

this opens a popup div with an iframe in, and making the SRC of the iframe the value of the a href item

I have a function on another page using javascript:

```
function VoIP_Portal() {
    window.location = "/voip_portal";
}
```

how can i use a function to open the popup window with an SRC in the iframe?

Comment: Could you please clarify the difference between what you say you are able to do "this opens a popup div with an iframe in, and making the SRC of the iframe the value of the a href item" and what you want to do "how can i use a function to open the popup window with an SRC in the iframe"?  Those sound like the same thing to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a id="MiniPopupWindow" href="http://www.google.co.uk/">test</a> ??

window.location = "/voip_portal";
```

nedd a href

```
window.location.href = "/voip_portal";
```

Comment: `window.location = 'http://www.example.com' is a synonym of window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com'` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cookie to achieve it. In case your request can be handled on the server side it will be easier, you can send the required parameters to server ans serve your page from there. 
In case you want to solve it with just JavaScript then you can look into this solution. [Passing values from one page to another in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21475052/passing-values-from-one-page-to-another-in-javascript)

Regards,
HBK