# Keeping score in HTML game

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a simple HTML game and each page has a single question. How do I keep score so that if the person gets the correct answer, the score is incremented and then when the game is over or the wrong answer is selected within the game, the game over page it shows the score. What options do I have and are there any possible ways to implement all of this in one single page rather than several pages?

Comment: how do i add the java code in html to keep the score

Comment: Could you at least provide some code? We can't tell you what to do without a code sample.

Comment: @noname we're just as unsure as you are. It completely depends on the existing code of your game.

Comment: How are you creating this game. Are you using any scripting languages? You won't be able to implement a scoring system without a scripting language.

Comment: how do i paste the code its telling me its too long

Comment: basically , i have made this game using javascript,css and html ,but the only problem is the score

Comment: "page1.html" consist of first question . "page2.html" consist of another question  , i just need to keep score which adds +1 on every correct answer ,and display the "best" and "score" on the game over page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple web pages with questions, you will need to constantly pass the scores from one html page to another. If you would like to do that, here is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21475052/passing-values-from-one-page-to-another-in-javascript) that will teach you that. The other option is keep all of the questions on one page and use JavaScript to show a new question each time the previous questions has been answered. Here is the full code sample:

```
   <html>
<head>
<title>Ten Questions</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var score = 0;
    var questions = 10;

    function start() {
        if (questions == 10) {
            document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = "What car brand out of the following options is German?";
            document.getElementById("option1").innerHTML = "Mercedes Benz";
            document.getElementById("option2").innerHTML = "Toyota";
            document.getElementById("option3").innerHTML = "Skoda";
        }

        else if (questions == 9) {
            document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = "What is the biggest country in the world?";
            document.getElementById("option1").innerHTML = "Fiji";
            document.getElementById("option2").innerHTML = "United States of America";
            document.getElementById("option3").innerHTML = "Russia";
        }

        else if (questions == 8) {
            document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = "What is the biggest river in the world?";
            document.getElementById("option1").innerHTML = "Amazon River";
            document.getElementById("option2").innerHTML = "Nile River";
            document.getElementById("option3").innerHTML = "Hudson River";
        }

        else if (questions == 7) {
            document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = "What does HP stand for?";
            document.getElementById("option1").innerHTML = "Hewlett Packard";
            document.getElementById("option2").innerHTML = "Howard Powell";
            document.getElementById("option3").innerHTML = "Honda Panda";
        }

        else if (questions == 6) {
            document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = "What does PM stand for?";
            document.getElementById("option1").innerHTML = "Post Meridien";
            document.getElementById("option2").innerHTML = "Post Man";
            document.getElementById("option3").innerHTML = "P M";
        }

        else if (questions == 5) {
            document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = "Who created Facebook?";
            document.getElementById("option1").innerHTML = "Bill Gates";
            document.getElementById("option2").innerHTML = "Mark Zuckerburg";
            document.getElementById("option3").innerHTML = "Steve Wozniak";
        }

        else if (questions == 4) {
            document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = "What is a banana made of?";
            document.getElementById("option1").innerHTML = "A banana";
            document.getElementById("option2").innerHTML = "Small hair-like strands";
            document.getElementById("option3").innerHTML = "Steve Wozniak";
        }

        else if (questions == 3) {
            document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = "What does LCD stand for?";
            document.getElementById("option1").innerHTML = "Light crystal display";
            document.getElementById("option2").innerHTML = "Large crystal display";
            document.getElementById("option3").innerHTML = "Liquid crystal display";
        }

        else if (questions == 2) {
            document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = "How many wheels does a car have?";
            document.getElementById("option1").innerHTML = "12";
            document.getElementById("option2").innerHTML = "6";
            document.getElementById("option3").innerHTML = "4";
        }

        else if (questions == 1) {
            document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = "Who is Microsoft's new CEO?";
            document.getElementById("option1").innerHTML = "Satcha Nadella";
            document.getElementById("option2").innerHTML = "Bill Gates";
            document.getElementById("option3").innerHTML = "Mark Zuckerburg";
        }

        else if (questions == 0) {
            document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("option1").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("option2").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("option3").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Your score was: " + score;
        }

    }

    function answer(question) {
        if (questions == 10) {
            if (question == 1) {
                score++; 
                questions--;
                start();
            }

            else if (question == 2) {
                score = score;
                questions--;
                start();
            }

            else if (question == 3) {
                score = score;
                questions--;
                start();
            }
        }

        else if (questions == 9) {
            if (question == 1) {
                score = score;
                questions--;
                start();
            }

            else if (question == 2) {
                score = score;
                questions--;
                start();
            }

            else if (question == 3) {
                score++;
                questions--;
                start();
            }
        }

        else if (questions == 8) {
            if (question == 1) {
                score = score;
                questions--;
                start();
            }

            else if (question == 2) {
                score++;
                questions--;
                start();
            }

            else if (question == 3) {
                score = score;
                questions--;
                start();
            }
        }

        else if (questions == 7) {
            if (question == 1) {
                score++;
                questions--;
                start();
            }

            else if (question == 2) {
                score = score;
                questions--;
                start();
            }

            else if (question == 3) {
                score = score;
                questions--;
                start();
            }
        }

        else if (questions == 6) {
            if (question == 1) {
                score++;
                questions--;
                start();
            }

            else if (question == 2) {
                score = score;
                questions--;
                start();
            }

            else if (question == 3) {
                score = score;
                questions--;
                start();
            }
        }

        else if (questions == 5) {
            if (question == 1) {
                score = score;
                questions--;
                start();
            }

            else if (question == 2) {
                score++;
                questions--;
                start();
            }

            else if (question == 3) {
                score = score;
                questions--;
                start();
            }
        }

        else if (questions == 4) {
            if (question == 1) {
                score = score;
                questions--;
                start();
            }

            else if (question == 2) {
                score++;
                questions--;
                start();
            }

            else if (question == 3) {
                score = score;
                questions--;
                start();
            }
        }

        else if (questions == 3) {
            if (question == 1) {
                score = score;
                questions--;
                start();
            }

            else if (question == 2) {
                score = score;
                questions--;
                start();
            }

            else if (question == 3) {
                score++;
                questions--;
                start();
            }
        }

        else if (questions == 2) {
            if (question == 1) {
                score = score;
                questions--;
                start();
            }

            else if (question == 2) {
                score = score;
                questions--;
                start();
            }

            else if (question == 3) {
                score++;
                questions--;
                start();
            }
        }

        else if (questions == 1) {
            if (question == 1) {
                score++;
                questions--;
                start();
            }

            else if (question == 2) {
                score = score;
                questions--;
                start();
            }

            else if (question == 3) {
                score = score;
                questions--;
                start();
            }
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
 <body onload="javascript:start()">
 <div>
<span id="question">
The question will be changed dynamically so the text here doesn't matter
    </span><br />
    <button onclick="javascript:answer(1)" id="option1">Random Answer 1</button><br />
    <button onclick="javascript:answer(2)" id="option2">Random Answer 2</button><br />
    <button onclick="javascript:answer(3)" id="option3">Random Answer   3</button><br />
<font face="Tahoma" color="red"><span id="score"></span></font>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, visit [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_function_undefined) site and paste the code and see how it works.

Comment: use local storage , check my answer

Comment: i really appreciate your help ,please provide me with full sample code ,i am still new to all this so bear with me ,i find it a little confusing

Comment: I have updated the question now. You can use the link I provided at the bottom to copy the code and see how it works.

Comment: this solved my problem ,thank you very much :D

Answer (score 1):

```
var score = "10";
localStorage.setItem("score", score);
```

And in any page (like when the page has loaded), get it like:

```
var score = localStorage.getItem("score");
```

for more : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API#localStorage

anyways why don't you use, `PHP`. you don't have to create so many single pages for each question

and if you can't for some reason , go for `jquery` . easy to learn , great documentation. that too can help u in making things easy and interactive

Comment: thank you very much for your answer , do i need to create a new localstorage page to store the scores ? because i need to include everything on its own page

Comment: no browser maintains it. you simply use above lines to save and retrieve data. Leave everything else on browser

Comment: i am very new to javascript ,i am still a beginner ,so its very confusing

Comment: awesome start using jquery , it has all tutorials/documention on it's function , its also called modern javascript . its a framework

Comment: my question only has two choices "true" or "false" ,so how can i add this code to add the score everytime the person gives a correct answer,, lets say my first page's answer is "true" ,the person clicks "true" and  goes to "page2" ,how do i write this code to add +1 score

Comment: thank you very much , please bear with me with my sill queestions

Comment: if u can't add in javascript why the hell you are creating game, first learn and deploy small codes. Are you trying to climb roof without ladder and wasting others time to be footstep