# How to pass the value of a variable in page 1 to page 2 in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery function that counts the number of images (eg. 3 images) in a gallery.

```
var imageNumber =  $(".ox-images-gallery img").length;  //value=3
```

How can I pass the value of `imageNumber` from the current page to another page using jQuery or Javascript?

I tried with:

**Page 1**

```
localStorage.setItem('val',imageNumber)
```

and

**Page 2**

```
localStorage.getItem('val');
```

but the problem is I must go to page 1 first so that the correct value of `imageNumber` is displayed on page 2. Any other approaches to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing values from one page to another in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21475052/passing-values-from-one-page-to-another-in-javascript)

Comment: Have you taken a look on passing image number in location query string? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870512/how-to-obtaining-the-querystring-from-the-current-url-with-javascript , like PAGE1_URL?imagenum=3

Comment: I don't think I can pass the value through a url parameter since my page's url will keep on changing based on the action performed. Any idea?

Comment: of course you have to go to where the value is set first to set the value. How else is the value going to be set except in the page that sets the value?

Comment: @JaromandaX You got the point here. Thanks.

Comment: how about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404891/how-to-pass-values-from-one-page-to-another-in-jquery

Answer (score 1):

```
//save a value
sessionStorage.setItem("name", "Nicholas");

//retrieve item
var name = sessionStorage.getItem("name");
```